# pydoc.ErrorDuringImport: problem in speechbrain.lobes.models.huggingface_wav2vec - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this library isn't loading. I have `transformers` installed correctly. What version mismatching is occuring here and how to fix it?

Error occurs in line `import transformers`. Error output is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 439, in safeimport
    module = __import__(path)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speechbrain\lobes\models\huggingface_wav2vec.py", line 27, in <module>
    import transformers
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import dependency_versions_check
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .generic import (
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\generic.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .import_utils import is_flax_available, is_tf_available, is_torch_available, is_torch_fx_proxy
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 213, in <module>
    torch_version = version.parse(_torch_version)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 49, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    data = self.construct_object(node)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 154, in construct_object
    data = self.construct_non_recursive_object(node)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 196, in construct_non_recursive_object
    for _dummy in generator:
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 674, in construct_yaml_map
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 445, in construct_mapping
    return BaseConstructor.construct_mapping(self, node, deep=deep)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 261, in construct_mapping
    value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 154, in construct_object
    data = self.construct_non_recursive_object(node)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 191, in construct_non_recursive_object
    data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)
    nextmodule = safeimport('.'.join(parts[:n+1]), forceload)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 213, in <module>
    torch_version = version.parse(_torch_version)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 49, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\Users\afsar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by manually setting the torch version in library `torch.__version__ = 2.0.0+cpu`. The version was getting `None` value before.